# Wicket 1.5 and JSP/servlet wrapping

Tags: jsp, servlets, wicket, wicket-1.5, requestdispatcher

In the project I'm on we want to upgrade from Wicket 1.4 to 1.5. After some work we got most things working OK.

However one major thing is not working yet. There's a need to wrap old JSP/servlets into the new Wicket based application and the old 1.4-approach is not working anymore.

Simplified html output in 1.4

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        wrappedContentFromJsp
    </div>  
<body>
```

Simplified html output in 1.5

```
<body>
    wrappedContentFromJsp   
    <div id="container">        
    </div>  
<body>
```

So, all the **JSP content renders outside the tag that we like to wrap it in**.

The wrapping magic happens in our internal `AbstractServletWrapperPanel` and the `WebMarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupStream markupStream)` override. However, **in Wicket 1.5 we can't invoke `markupStream.next()` since it's no longer provided**. I have not found a way around this yet.

Working code for 1.4 with a sample panel implementation as reference:

```
public abstract class AbstractServletWrapperPanel extends Panel {

    public AbstractServletWrapperPanel(String id, final  String servletName, String tagId) {
        super(id);
        add(new WebMarkupContainer(tagId) {

            @Override
            protected void onRender(MarkupStream markupStream) {
                markupStream.next();
                try {
                    WebRequestCycle cycle = (WebRequestCycle) RequestCycle.get();
                    ServletRequest request = cycle.getWebRequest().getHttpServletRequest();
                    ServletResponse response = cycle.getWebResponse().getHttpServletResponse();
                    ServletContext context = ((WebApplication) Application.get()).getServletContext();
                    RequestDispatcher rd = context.getNamedDispatcher(servletName);
                    if (rd != null) {
                        rd.include(request, response);
                    } else {
                        // handling...
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // handling...
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

//Impl
public class WrapperPanel extends AbstractServletWrapperPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public WrapperPanel(String id, final String servletName) {
        super(id, servletName, "wrappedContentId");
    }   
}

//WrapperPanel html
<body>
    <wicket:panel>
        <wicket:container wicket:id="wrappedContentId"/>
    </wicket:panel>
</body>
```

In the 1.5 version I'm getting the request and response via `(HttpServletRequest)RequestCycle.get().getRequest().getContainerRequest()` and `(HttpServletResponse)RequestCycle.get().getResponse().getContainerResponse()`

Then I've tried to:

- use the onRender()-magic without `markupStream.next()` that's no longer provided in 1.5
- move it to `onComponentTagBody(MarkupStream markupStream, ComponentTag tag)`

  - Note: To invoke onComponentTagBody() I had to open up the wicket:container tag `<wicket:container wicket:id="wrappedContentId"></wicket:container>`.  I also tried without invoking `markupStream.next()` as that step is performed in `Component.internalRenderComponent()` just before `onComponentTagBody` is invoked at all.
- move it to `onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag)`
- combined above with setting `setRenderBodyOnly(true)` in the `WebMarkupContatiner.onInitialize()`
- use a `<div>` tag instead of a `wicket:container`
- use debug mode to track down the rendering process of 1.5. But still, I guess I'm missing out some key part of the new 1.5 way of rendering components.

Since it's not an option to migrate all that JSP functionality to Wicket anytime soon this is kind of a showstopper for us at the moment.

For reference, the 1.4 way of doing this is much similar to the approach I found in the article [jsp-and-wicket-sitting-in-a-tree](http://herebebeasties.com/2007-03-01/jsp-and-wicket-sitting-in-a-tree/) and on the [Wicket wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/including-jsp-files-in-html-templates.html)

Any help solving this issue would be very appreciated!

[EDIT]
After a suggestion from TheStijn I've also tried invoking `getAssociatedMarkupStream()` from `onRender()` but that raises the following error: `org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupNotFoundException: Markup of type 'html' for component '... AbstractServletWrapperPanel$1' not found.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After great help and pointers from Martin Grigorov I found the solution to this. To follow the process of getting there, hava look at the [user's forum](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Wicket-1-5-and-JSP-servlet-wrapping-td4407174.html)

Please note that following is just the raw output of trying to get it to work at all, there might be some nicer way to "package" it. So take it for what it is.

```
//Stripped code for clarity

@Override
public void onComponentTagBody(MarkupStream markupStream, ComponentTag tag) {

 //Set up mock response and dispatch.   
 ServletContext context = WebApplication.get().getServletContext(); 
 ServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)RequestCycle.get().getRequest().getContainerRequest();
 MockResponse mockResponse = new MockResponse((HttpServletResponse)RequestCycle.get().getResponse().getContainerResponse());
 RequestDispatcher rd = context.getNamedDispatcher(aServletName);
 rd.include(request, mockResponse);

 //As in Wicket's Include.onComponentTagBody(MarkupStream markupStream, ComponentTag tag)
 replaceComponentTagBody(markupStream, tag, mockResponse.getOutput());
}


private static class MockResponse extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {    
 ServletOutputStream servletStream;
 ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream;

 public MockResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
  super(response);      
  byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  servletStream = new ServletOutputStream() {

    @Override
    public void write(int b) {
       byteStream.write(b);
     }
   };
 }

 @Override
 public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() {
  return servletStream;
 }

 public String getOutput() {
    //NOTE: Remember to clean up IO in real usage...
    return byteStream.toString("UTF-8"); //Provide desired encoding
  }  
}
```

So why didn't I use `org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.mockMockHttpServletResponse` instead?
For some reason neither `getWriter()` or `getOutputStream()` got invoked, but I might look further into that later.

Answer (score 1):

Not used this before but `(Web)MarkupContainer` has a method `getAssociatedMarkupStream` which returns the `MarkupStream`, this should work for you.

It is mentioned in the 1.5 migration guide but not very well:

> On the same topic: onRender(MarkupStream) has been changed to
>   onRender(); no more MarkupStream. You can get for every component once
>   you called render() via getMarkupStream().

https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/migration-to-wicket-15.html#MigrationtoWicket1.5-Componentrendering

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  
I've read that part of the guide a couple of times, but did never find the method `getMarkupStream()` :)  
However `getAssociatedMarkupStream()` does not work that well either. I get following exception:
`org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupNotFoundException: Markup of type 'html' for component '... AbstractServletWrapperPanel$1' not found.`
I see it invokes `MarkupContainer.getAssociatedMarkup()` and then `MarkupFactory.get().getMarkup(this, false)`

But I have no problem finding the markup if I invoke `getMarkup()` from `onRender()` explicitly.

Comment: Did you already try overriding `onComponentTagBody` instead of onRender?

Comment: Yepp, sorry if it wasn't clear enough. But as I wrote in the question I had to open up the tag to accomplish that `<wicket:container></wicket:container>`. I will edit the question and add that I also tried without `markupStream.next()` as that step is performed in `Component.internalRenderComponent()` just before `onComponentTagBody` is invoked.

Comment: Worked out a solution with some mailing list help as you can see in my answer. Anyhow, thanks for your help (can't vote up yet, to low rep for that...)